# How to effectively use the BitVector Module In Perl to find the XOR of two numbers?

Tags: perl, xor, bitvector

I am having trouble figuring out how to effectively use the BitVector module in Perl to find the Exclusive Or (XOR) of two numbers in hexadecimal form.

This is my whole code:

```
use Bit::Vector;
$bits = Bit::Vector->Word_Bits();  #  bits in a machine word

print "This program will take two numbers and will return the XOR of the two numbers.\n";

print "Enter the first number in hexadecimal form:\n";
$firstHexNumber = <STDIN>;
$vector = Bit::Vector->new($bits, $firstHexNumber);  #  bit vector constructor

print "Enter the second number in hexadecimal form:\n";
$secondHexNumber = <STDIN>;
$vector2 = Bit::Vector->new($bits, $secondHexNumber);  #  bit vector constructor

$vector3 = Bit::Vector->new($bits);  #  bit vector constructor
$vector3->Xor($vector,$vector2);

print $vector3;
```

I am not sure if I am doing the syntax right for the BitVector module. 
If I try to run it, I get an output like this.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFS6I.png)

When I input 1 and 16 as my arguments, the output is supposed to be 17.
Please help me see what's wrong with my code to get the output correct.
Thank you.

Comment: Note: Always `use strict; use warnings;` and declare lexical variables with `my`. And you should probably remove the trailing newline character when reading input from STDIN: i.e.: `chomp(my $firstHexNumber = <STDIN>)`

Comment: In the code you give prompt for _hex_ numbers - if it is so then you should refer them in description as _0x01_ and _0x17_ and expected output should be _0x16_. In binary representation the result should be _00010110_. Also you forgot to **chomp** input data.

Comment: Correction: In binary representation the result should be _0b00010110_.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you, I went ahead and added all those and fixed up a little myself, and it worked perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`new_Hex()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Bit-Vector/Vector.pod#CLASS-METHODS1) and [`to_Hex()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Bit-Vector/Vector.pod#CLASS-METHODS1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bit::Vector;
my $bits = Bit::Vector->Word_Bits();  #  bits in a machine word
my $firstHexNumber = "1";
my $vector = Bit::Vector->new_Hex($bits, $firstHexNumber); 
my $secondHexNumber = "17";
my $vector2 = Bit::Vector->new_Hex($bits, $secondHexNumber);
my $vector3 = Bit::Vector->new($bits);  #  bit vector constructor
$vector3->Xor($vector,$vector2);
print $vector3->to_Hex;
```

**Output**:

```
0000000000000016
```

Comment: Note: all _hex_ numbers pre-pended with _0x_ to indicate that it is a _hex_ number. Your output represent _octal_ representation of a number (starts with _0_ and has numbers in range of 0..7). For _binary_ representation a number starts with _0b_ and follows with numbers in range 0..1.

Answer (score 4):

No need for a module.

```
# Make sure the bitwise feature wasn't activated (e.g. by `use 5.022;`)
no if $] >= 5.022, feature => qw( bitwise );

my $hex1 = '012345';
my $hex2 = '000AAA';

my $hex_xor = unpack('H*', pack('H*', $hex1) ^ pack('H*', $hex2) );

say $hex_xor;  # 0129ef
```

or (5.22+)

```
# Safe. Feature accepted without change in 5.28.
use experimental qw( bitwise );

my $hex1 = '012345';
my $hex2 = '000AAA';

my $hex_xor = unpack('H*', pack('H*', $hex1) ^. pack('H*', $hex2) );

say $hex_xor;  # 0129ef
```

or (5.28+)

```
use feature qw( bitwise );  # Or: use 5.028;  # Or: use v5.28;

my $hex1 = '012345';
my $hex2 = '000AAA';

my $hex_xor = unpack('H*', pack('H*', $hex1) ^. pack('H*', $hex2) );

say $hex_xor;  # 0129ef
```

These solutions work with numbers of arbitrary length, which is why I assume Bit::Vector was selected for use. (Just pad the numbers so that both have the same length if necessary, or Perl will effectively right-pad with zeroes.)

Comment: Discussion in perlop in the [Bitwise String Operators section](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators)